How to get a field from another model in odoo
I want to access the seats_number field from the plane model when the name field in the plane model is equal to the plane_id firld from the flight model
@api.depends('plane_id')
def _compute_seats_number(self):
    for flight in self:
        for plane in self.env['airport.plane'].search([]):
            if flight.plane_id == plane.name:
                flight.seats_number = plane.seats_number
                break            


It doesn't work, it doesn't change the values in the field value when the condition is satified

You can add the condition to the search domain and use the id field instead of the name field (which is probably a char field)

What about using a related field instead?
class FlightModel(models.Model):
    # usual stuff

    plane_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="my.plane.model",
        string="Plane",
    )
    seats_number = fields.Integer(
        related="plane_id.seats_number",
    )



I did that two days ago and it worked, but, thank you for your answer, i'm going to mark it as yes.
